# Selenium - Read from Excel using Apache POI gives Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cell index must be >= 0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written a simple Excel utility to extract data from the excel input file based on the column headers provided as input

**Excel Utility Program**

```
public Object getExcelData(String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum) {
    
    int col_num=-1;
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
    if(index==-1)
        return "";
    
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
    
    row = sheet.getRow(0);
    
    for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++)
    {
        if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName.trim()))
                col_num=i;
    }
    
    row = sheet.getRow(rowNum -1);
    cell = row.getCell(col_num);
    
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    Object excelData = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
    
    return excelData;
            
}
```

**The input file is attached here which has multiple rows and columns values**
[image]

**When I use the Excel Utility program to access the column values at the 2nd row the code works absolutely fine**

```
public class Sample {

    static String excelPath = "./src/main/java/TestData/TestData.xlsx";
        static ExcelUtil2 excel;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        excel = new ExcelUtil2();
        excel.setupExcel(excelPath, "Sheet1");
        //int number = excel.getRowCount(sheet);
        //System.out.println("Rowcount is: "+number);
        
        Object result = excel.getExcelData("Sheet1", "Order Total", 2);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output = $27.66**

**The same excel utility program when used to extract the column values of the 5th row, gives -  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cell index must be >= 0**

```
public class Sample {

    static String excelPath = "./src/main/java/TestData/TestData.xlsx";
    //static String sheet = "Sheet1";
    static ExcelUtil2 excel;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        excel = new ExcelUtil2();
        excel.setupExcel(excelPath, "Sheet1");
        //int number = excel.getRowCount(sheet);
        //System.out.println("Rowcount is: "+number);
        
        Object result = excel.getExcelData("Sheet1", "Zipcode", 5);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cell index must be >= 0
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.getCell(XSSFRow.java:203)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.getCell(XSSFRow.java:190)
    at com.qa.vusevapor.Util.ExcelUtil2.getExcelData(ExcelUtil2.java:67)
    at com.qa.vusevapor.Page.Sample.main(Sample.java:17)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the method ie. getExcelData ,you have hard-coded the row number
i.e :

```
 row = sheet.getRow(0);
```

hence it is reading all the attributes values from row one

**In the first case :**

```
int rowNum = 2 , 
so 
     row = sheet.getRow(rowNum -1);  // this will give (2-1) =1
     cell = row.getCell(col_num);    // col_num is 7 , since i start with 0 , 
                                     // so cell becomes (1,7) , so it will print Output = $27.66
```

**In the second case :**

```
   for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++)
    {
        if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName.trim()))
                col_num=i;
    }
```

> here colName = 'Zipcode', which would never match on row number
> zero, and value of col_num=-1 , that will cause the Exception in
> thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cell index must be >= 0

**Please find my fix, this should work for both the cases:**

```
    public Object getExcelData(String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum) {

    int col_num = -1;
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
    if (index == -1)
        return "";

    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);

    row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
        if (row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName.trim()))
            col_num = i;
    }

    row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
    cell = row.getCell(col_num);

    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    Object excelData = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);

    return excelData;

}
```

Comment: Thanks - so how do I fix this Excel Utility program?

Comment: try to paramerterized this : row = sheet.getRow(0);

Comment: @Bimlesh I have added the fix in the answer

Comment: Thanks Anurag - This solution is working perfectly fine with all the scenarios.           
 Could you please help me understand the logic behind  row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 2);?

Comment: @Bimlesh as per your test case you are passing row number =2  , means you considering row number where you have actual value of the corresponding header(Order Total) which is actually at  row number=1, but in excel row number starts from zero, so to point row number 1 we need to subtract from parameter i.e 2-2 = 0, same for where you providing row number = 5, 5-2 = 3 (that's pointing header Zipcode) , hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Anurag for the detailed explanation. Indeed very helpful.